# Integration testing using SQL, JMS etc

Tags: sql, jvm, cucumber, jms

More of a doubt, than an issue. I have a Spring application which exposes both JMS and HTTP endpoints. I have a couple of databases it interacts with, a couple of other services it interfaces via HTTP(s).

Let us say, I want to develop an integration test suite for this application - using Cucumber, or the likes.

Do I provision a separate (preferably in-memory or mock) IT (integration test) environment before the suite starts up and tear it down after I'm done, or do I host it on my developer instance and run my IT against it?

Hosting it on my developer instance is a bit straight-forward, though I seem to have a liking for doing it in-situ, considering the number of external dependencies I can escape for running the test.

If someone has done the in-memory (or mock) way to achieve the same, do you have any resources to share?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for in-memory DB for running your test, you can use [h2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) database. But personally I don't recommend going that path, as its never a true test reason h2 database is never gonna be your production database. So some of your queries may pass with h2 but the same SQL will fail in live environment.

 Your Integration Tests should run against production like environment, and for that reason either you can run your test pointing to a **dedicated IT environment** (as you mentioned) or you can use something like [**testcontainer**](https://www.testcontainers.org/), putting your environment in a docker container & run your test suite.